# Can't load the full HTML content of a webpage

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to load a [webpage](https://www.vezeeta.com/en/dr/Doctor-Abd-Elrahman-Gouda-Donia-Internal-Medicine#totalReviews) that has about 1200 reviews about a doctor. I want to scrape these reviews. My problem is that these reviews are loaded 10 at a time, making to process of retrieving the reviews manually very tedious.

By running the command  `document.getElementById("LoadMore").click()` I can load 10 more reviews. However, when I put this command in a for loop it only loads another 10 reviews. I need to load all of the reviews to the webpage in order to scrape them. My problem is that I don't know the proper way to do so with JavaScript.

NOTE:
I've tried this while loop

```
while(document.getElementById("LoadMore")){
  document.getElementById("LoadMore").click();
}
```

But the webpage crashed.

Please feel free to ask if something isn't clear.

Comment: You are probably better off scraping the data directly from their API instead of their webpage. The request URL looks like this   `https://www.vezeeta.com/en/DoctorProfile/GetDoctorReviews?entityId=53743&sortByComment=true&pageNumber=3`

Answer (score 0):

In your while condition you have a truthy value. So you get an infinite loop like `while (true) ...` and thus you crash the page.

One of possible solutions is to use some check for a new content, and only then click the button. Or you can use a setTimeout hack, but it is not so good one due to timing issues.

But the best solution is try to load content directly by the API endpoint which is provide this data to the webpage you scraping form.